# ASP.Net Core Identity with distributed session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity in my ASP.NET application, but running on two webservers on AWS, and have the problem that when you're logged in on one server, you are not logged in on the other because they don't share the same session.

This is also a problem e.g. when I'm deploying a new version of my application - then the users will be logged out and have to log in again.

I have tried adding a distributed cache with Redis, in my `Configure` method:

```
app.UseSession();
```

And my `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "uri-to-redis-server";
    options.InstanceName = "name";
});

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddMvc();

services.AddSession();
```

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Can you try storing the identity related data in a database? You may also search for REDIS based ASP.Net Identity provider, I am sure you will find some good nuget package.

Comment: Identity does not use session, so problem with something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! First, I set the cookie options to have an ExpireTimeSpan:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(24);
    o.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Furthermore, when using external login, I set the `isPersistent` argument of `_signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync` to `true`